# Encontrar arquivo no diretório templates

Tags: django, django-2.0

Em versões até a 2.2.5 do Django eu colocava meus arquivos html que eram passados na view da seguinte forma :

```
myapp
   templates
       myapp
          index.html
```

Mas no django 2.2.6 e 2.2.7 quando faço isso dá o seguinte erro :

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /
```

Mas quando eu faço :

```
myapp
   templates
       index.html
```

O template é encontrado.

Como nessas versões mais novas o Django  faz o tratamento para identificar 2 templates com o mesmo nome sem precisar do subdiretório para distinguir ?

Comment: Beto, você não colocou o mais importante na sua pergunta... como você está chamando este template? Pois na sua primeira estrutura de pastas bastaria chamar `myapp/index.html` que estaria tudo OK...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que seja uma configuração no arquivo `settings.py` do projeto.

Verifique se tem a variável TEMPLATES, dessa forma:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Importante:

`'DIRS': ['templates']`: Define o nome das pastas onde o django vai procurar pelos templates, no seu caso, é templates mesmo.

`'APP_DIRS': True`: Informa se o django deve procurar pelos templates dentro das aplicações, no seu caso, é True mesmo.

Fazendo essa configuração ele vai encontrar templates dentro da pasta 'templates' dentro da sua aplicação.

Outra coisa:

Se sua estrutura estiver:

```
myapp
   templates
       myapp
          index.html
```

O caminho do seu template não é `index.html` e sim `myapp/index.html`

Espero que te ajude.
Abraço.